# Basecamp 3 API 400 Error on Create Todo List

Tags: basecamp

Been troubleshooting for a while and can't come up with an answer. I run get commands with no problem so list basecamps, todos, accounts, etc. All that's working fine. It's when I POST to todolists.json where I'm having problems.

I'm sending to this URL:

```
https://3.basecampapi.com/3266090/buckets/1940710/todosets/296431359/todolists.json
```

Headers:

```
[0] => Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
[1] => User-Agent: Template Deployer (s****d@***.org)
[2] => Authorization: Bearer [working token]
[3] => If-None-Match:
```

POST payload:

```
name=foobar
```

And here's the response I'm getting:

```
[result] => Array
    (
        [status] => 400
        [error] => Bad Request
    )

[headers] => Array
    (
        [Server] => nginx
        [Date] => Fri, 18 Nov 2016 21:05:44 GMT
        [Content-Type] => application/json; charset=utf-8
        [Content-Length] => 36
        [Connection] => keep-alive
        [X-Request-Id] => ab71cfaa-e24c-4a38-b1af-44fe8ae8d147
        [X-Runtime] => 0.456205
        [Strict-Transport-Security] => max-age=15552000; includeSubDomains; preload
        [X-Queue-Time] => 0.0010805130004882812
        [Set-Cookie] => force-primary-dc=true;Max-Age=5;Path=/;Version=1;
    )

[code] => 400
[content_type] => application/json; charset=utf-8
```

I've tried several combinations of name, description and project (from another thread I found about someone else's problem), to no avail. I don't even know what else to try.

Any Ideas?

Answer (score 0):

And it's because I'm not a smart person :)

Answer: the payload needs to be json encoded: `{"content":"Do this!"}` rather than url encoded: `name=foobar`

Problem Solved!